# Tag Merge or delete the wrong one

Tags: feature-request, bug

The two tags:

javascript and javacscript  (I think the latter is a mistake)

should be merged, or delete the 2nd one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for catching that; I re-tagged the one question with the incorrect version but I don't see any way to delete it.  Maybe somebody with a higher rep could do that?

Comment: I think you need 500 rep to delete tags. thanks.